# How to stop Automatic MP3 importing + playback when downloading using Safari

Tags: macos, safari, media

I wish to retain the 'Open "safe" files after downloading' check box, as it contains things like images and pdf's that I do want to automatically open using Preview.

Although am sick of downloading MP3 files which are automatically added to iTunes and are immediately played back.

Anyway to stop this behaviour for JUST mp3's?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a good answer that Chris has - You can also change the default application using the OS.

Click get info on an .mp3 that you already have in your finder, there is a section "Open With", you may have to turn down the triangle.

If you change the app (to say QuickTime) or to another app that opens quickly, then click "Change All", your system will now by default use that application top open MP3 files.

That will at least get around the problem of them opening and importing in iTunes, and disrupting the currently playing music as well.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might try changing the default application for `.mp3` files.

1. Download and install [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/).
2. In the **Default Apps** preference pane (now available in the *System Preferences* application), select the **Extensions** tab.
3. From the list of extensions, select **mp3**.
   Either

   - scroll to and click on **mp3**, or
   - click on any extension in the list and then type “mp3”.
4. For the *Default Application* popup menu, select **<disable>** (or some other application).

If you select **<disabled>**, you will be unable to automatically open `.mp3` files in the normal ways (e.g. double-clicking on it in *Finder*), but you will still have the *Open With* submenu in *Finder*’s contextual menu for file items.

If you select some other application, it will automatically open `.mp3` files when you download them with *Safari*, but you may prefer the on-open behavior of *QuickTime Player* (or some other application) to that of *iTunes*.

Answer (score 0):

To disable it for all the files :

1. Go to Safari preferences
2. Disable the Open safe files after downloading[image]